# Sources remaining in the open part of the circuit after the switch is closed

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, switches, current-source, laplace-transform

Below there is a circuit from the book Nilsson & Riedel Electrical Circuits 9th Edition.

[image]

The switch in the circuit been in position x for a long time. At t = 0, the switch moves instantaneously to position y. And the circuit is as in the figure below (**in the s-domain**).

[image]

But how can we still have the current source and how did we find the value of this current source we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that \$\mathcal{L}\left\{\,v^{'}\right\}=sV-v_{_0}\$? Call the left node, after switching, as \$v\$ and the right node as \$u\$. Then the KCL for the left node is \$C v^{'}+\frac1{R}v=\frac1{R}u\$. Initially, \$v_{_0}\ne 0\$ but \$u_{_0}=0\$. This first node's KCL is then \$\mathcal{L}\left\{C v^{'}+\frac1{R}v\right\}=\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac1{R}u\right\}\$, but this expands into \$C\mathcal{L}\left\{ v^{'}\right\}+\frac1{R}\mathcal{L}\left\{v\right\}=\frac1{R}\mathcal{L}\left\{u\right\}\$ and then, taking into account that \$v_{_0}\ne 0\$, into \$C\left[\vphantom{\frac1{R}}sV-v_{_0}\right]+\frac1{R}V=\frac1{R}U\$ and finally into \$CsV-Cv_{_0}+\frac1{R}V=\frac1{R}U\$. The \$Cv_{_0}\$ term there *looks like* some kind of current source/sink that was added to the node's KCL. Not so?

Note that the value for the current source they show has the magnitude of \$150\:\text{V}\cdot 625\:\text{nF}\$?